# Two Modals - One page. Opens the same Modal

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am just getting my feet wet for a very small website. I am completely new at HTML,CSS,JS,Bootstrap,etc. I am self-learning as I go. That said...

I am trying to make this page have two separate modals with different information on each one.

The problem I am running into is that it keeps showing the first modal and not the second. I have been searching all over for hours and trying different code, trying to learn what I am doing wrong, all articles and examples of modal forms says to change the ID. Which I've done.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="text-center">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm">Launch
         Modal Form 1</a>
      </div>    
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Write to us</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="text" id="form34" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form34">Your name</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm2">Launch
         Modal Form 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Test of 2nd modal</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
              
              <p> This is a random test </p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         (function(){
         
             var template = null
         
             $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                 if (template == null) {
                     template = $(this).html()
                 } else {
                     $(this).html(template)
                 }
                 // other initialization here, if you want to
             })
         
         })()
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the JavaScript snippet at the end of your page.

The buttons are opening the correct modals. But your code snippet at the end is copying the content of one modal when it's opened, then using it to overwrite the second modal when *that* one is opened.

You can remove the code snippet entirely, or else replace it with one that doesn't use global variables. I would use [`$.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store it on the `.modal` element itself:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="text-center">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm">Launch
         Modal Form 1</a>
      </div>    
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Write to us</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="text" id="form34" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form34">Your name</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm2">Launch
         Modal Form 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Test of 2nd modal</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
              
              <p> This is a random test </p>
              
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
     (function(){
         // instead of using a global template variable,
         // use jQuery.data() to store it on the .modal element itself
         // so it works with multiple modals

         $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
             if (!$(this).data('template')) {
                 $(this).data('template', $(this).html())
             } else {
                 $(this).html($(this).data('template'))
             }
             // other initialization here, if you want to
         })
     
     })()
  </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are awesome! You have no idea how long I was working on that! I appreciate your help so much!!!